# Can eigenvectors be scaled and still be eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Given the matrix:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The **eigenvalues** are:

$$λ_1 = 2,$$

$$λ_2 = 4.$$

To find the **eigenvectors**:

$$v_1 = \operatorname{nullity}(A - λ_1I),$$

$$v_2 = \operatorname{nullity}(A - λ_2I).$$

Which yielded the following eigenvectors for $v_1$:

$$
v_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{2}{3}\\
1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

However, I have seen this alternative eigenvector for $v_1$:

$$
v_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\
3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

> **Question:** Are both eigenvectors for $v_1$ correct? In other words, can you scale an eigenvector by any real number and it still be an eigenvector of that matrix?

This would make sense, as I believe we are only really interested in the direction (eigenvectors) and the factor by which the matrix scaled (eigenvalues). Thus, I would argue that the magnitude of the values within an eigenvector are meaningless. For example, the following eigenvector for $v_1$ is just as correct:

$$
v_1 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-44444\\
66666
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Which perhaps begs the question:**

> *Why aren't these called eigenvalues and eigendirections?*

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: you can scale them as you like; often, they are taken to have norm 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A formal proof of this statement could be the following: Let $A$ be a square matrix with eigenvector $v$ and eigenvalue $\lambda$ (i.e. $Av = \lambda v$). We would like to show that $cv = x$ is also an eigenvector, where $c \neq 0$ is a constant. This follows from

$$Ax = A(cv) = c (Av) = c (\lambda v) = \lambda (cv) = \lambda x.$$

Note that the case $c = 0$ has to be excluded since $x = 0$ is by definition never an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Jan's answer, the eigenvectors of a linear map corresponding to a certain eigenvalue form a subspace of their own. This is because linear combinations of eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue produce more eigenvectors:

Let ${v_i}$ be eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $T(\sum{a_iv_i}) = \sum{a_iT(v_i)} = \sum{a_i\lambda v_i} = \lambda\sum{a_iv_i}$. This shows that the linear combination is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.